# Python Dot-Product with Matrix-elements

Tags: python, numpy

I want to implement the following calculation in python :
[image]

With
[image] and
[image].

Here [image] are matrices themselves.
Thus python should compute a matrix-times-vector multiplication, where the vector-elements are matrices.Is this possible without a for-loop?

Comment: Ist es möglich im english zu erklären ;) ?

Comment: yes, sorry for that ;)

Comment: Is E always [1, 1; 1, -1] or can be arbitrary?

Comment: E is arbitrary but square. E and v can be of any size, as well as M.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using numpy:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: M1 = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

In [3]: M2 = np.array([[10, 20], [30, 40]])

In [4]: E = np.array([[1, 1], [1, -1]])

In [5]: v = np.array([M1, M2])

In [6]: np.tensordot(E, v, 1)
Out[6]: 
array([[[ 11,  22],
        [ 33,  44]],

       [[ -9, -18],
        [-27, -36]]])
```

Comment: The `einsum` equivalent is `np.einsum('ij,jkl->ikl', E, v)`.

Comment: Thanks, @hpaulj. I knew there would be some `einsum` way to do this, but did not know it off the top of my head.

Comment: I'd to fiddle around a bit; the symmetry of `E` makes the `ij` v `ji` ambiguous. But your choice of the `1` parameter makes most sense (last of `E`, first of `v`).

Answer (score 0):

if you're familiar with einstein summation notation, you can imagine E subscripted as E_ij, and v as v_jkl, and more generally write the np.tensordot in @steve-kern's example as:

`In [6]: np.einsum('ij,jkl',E,v)`